# Snapshots suffer from Short Term Memory Loss?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, boot, android-emulator

I have seen that despite repeatedly saving to snapshot, periodically (once in about 3 attempts to launch from snapshot) I get the error:

> emulator: ERROR: Unable to load VM from snapshot. The snapshot was saved for a
>   **different** hardware configuration

This forces me to go the old way (boot and wait 150-200 seconds) again try saving to snapshot and then launch. This phenomenon has been happening for quite some time now.

That said, I have settled for a system configuration (after all the only change in configuration from the default is that in the preferred setting all IMEs are disabled). That is it. No system apps installed like Google Play, etc. No system apps removed either. I have not changed the system/hardware configurations for the last one week.

I later came to know a command whereby the emulator can load from snapshot so that on closing it, the SDK doesn't save it to snapshot. Just run

```
emulator -no-snapshot-save -avd Andreud
```

in the terminal. I was relieved since

1. It will be good to not save to snapshot and save processing time, when you know you aren't making any more system/hardware configuration changes.

   I suspected that there were some unknown aberrations in saving to snapshots sometimes and is what resulted in the error, so avoid it rather than cure it.

Yesterday I discovered that the problem persisted! It persists to this day! What amazes me is that when I **no longer write** to the snapshot image, it still **forgets** the configurations stored in the snapshot so soon! I even tried to do it after freeing up RAM space by running solely the emulator and none else!

Any help to rectify this is welcome.

P.S.: I have given `-no-boot-anim` option to the `emulator` command as well. So if not loading from snapshot, at least the boot happens in less time.

Comment: Close Voters: While the Android Emulator is _primarily_ for developers, we long ago established that emulator questions may be of interest to some power users. I think this question is fine to stay open.